How to clone GitHub Wiki images that were auto-pasted?
I'm using GitHub Wiki pages.  I'm using Asciidoc, but I don't think that matters.  When I drop an image into the Wiki editing area, it makes a URL like this:
https://github.mycompany.com/ORG/repo_foobar/assets/402/773e8fc6-4278-4dbe-ab88-73dde53963ab

The core of that is the "assets" element.  What is that?  And how do I clone it?
I know how to clone the Wiki, and that gets me all the *.asciidoc files.  But not the images.
If I clone the main repository, I don't get anything like "assets" nor do I find anywhere all the *.png files I'm pasting.
I know I can put images in an explicit area of the code, then it would clone fine, but that's a lot of work compared to the very easy pasting.
How do I clone or otherwise back up all the images that are referenced in the Wiki?

Are you saying that when you clone the repository the images are not present in the clone, or that you cannot reference them using the url with "asset" in it?
